# Concise way to initialize a vector of user-defined datatype

Tags: c++

Okay, so I have a structure(below) and I want to initialize all its member to false. I also want a vector of size `stalls` of the structure `barn`. In other words, I want `stalls` copies of object structure `barn` with vector as container, and its members initialized.

```
struct barn {
    bool cow, board;
};
```

I have been using the following code to do so (terrible way of doing it):

```
vector<barn> barn_info;
for (int i = 0; i != stalls; ++i) {
    barn x; x.cow = false; x.board = false;
    barn_info.push_back(x);
}
```

Comment: Both answers below will work, but since you want both members to be `false`, all you need in this case is `vector<barn> barn_info(stalls);` The `vector` will contain `stalls` number of elements, and each element will be value-initialized, which will set both `bool` members to `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing that, most of them involve C++11:

If (and only if) you are using C++11, you can have

```
struct barn {
  bool cow = false;
  bool board = false;
}

vector<barn> barn_info(stalls);
```

Note that this does not work together with initializing them on the contructor. See [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members) for more on them.

If you do not want to have a constructor for a struct AND you don't initialize its fields as above, you can have something like this:

```
vector<barn> barn_info(stalls, {false, false})
```

The { } part are also described in the above link. You can see more ways of initializing a `std::vector` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

You can use the `.assign()` method of the `std::vector`, like this:

```
std::vector<barn> barn_info;
barn b; b.cow = false; b.board = false;
barn_info.assign(stalls, b); // assign 'stalls' positions the 'b' value
```

This works even if not using C++11. If using C++11 you can shorten it like:

```
barn_info.assign(stalls, {false, false});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct barn {
    bool cow, board;

    barn():cow(false),board(false){}
};

vector<barn> barn_info(n);
```

Comment: This would work without the constructor. The vector value-initializes them. Not that I'd complain about having such a constructor in general, though.

Comment: Is that a constructor? I don't know much about constructors. Could you be able to explain what the `{}` is for?

Comment: @IshaanSingh barn() is a constructor and {} is its body, but now it is empty

Comment: @chris What do you mean by "vector value-initializes them"?

Answer (score 1):

Use the vector constructor directly :

```
barn b {false, false; };

std::vector<barn> barn_info (stalls, b);
```

Comment: It is a struct initalizer, intialize the fields in order.

Comment: @IshaanSingh `vector<barn> barn_info (stalls, b);` means a vector with `stalls` elements which default value is `b`